# List the files in Directory and Copy-Replace them into another Directory in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to automate the below: Any help, please.
We have 2 directories as mentioned below, whenever we get new files in Directory-1, only they should be copied and replaced into Directory-2. How to achieve this in Linux scripting. Filename remains the same but the version will be different.

```
Directory-1:
FileOne_2.0.0.txt
FileTwo_3.0.0.txt

Directory-2:
FileOne_1.0.0.txt
FileTwo_2.0.0.txt
FileThree_3.0.0.txt
FileFive_5.0.0.txt
```

Comment: Make dir1 a symlink to dir2? :)

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I have to make some prechecks before copying so if I make symlink it will copy automatically. It would be better for me to have this in some script and run only whenever it is required.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that simple, lol. One could hope. ;)

Comment: Can you explain the logic you use to decide what you call "version"?

Comment: @franzisk: If there is change in the file then the version will be updated in the file. We have to ignore the version and get only the file name, compare that in the dir-2 if there is a file with the same name(ignoring its version) then delete this file and put the new file in its place.

Comment: I would expect a version increase from Directory-1 to Directory-2, and not a decrease

Comment: If you watch the closely the example given above, you can see that Directory-2 will always have the latest version after copying. If you have any code for the scripting then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (*on a test setup before you trust your real directories and files with it*):

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s extglob    # Enable extended globbing ( +([0-9]) ... )
shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Globs match files with names starting with '.'

srcdir='Directory-1'
destdir='Directory-2'

# A(n extended) glob pattern to match a version string (e.g. '543.21.0')
readonly kVERGLOB='+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])'

# shellcheck disable=SC2231 # (Bad warning re. unquoted ${kVERGLOB})
for srcpath in "$srcdir"/*_${kVERGLOB}.txt; do
    srcfile=${srcpath##*/}  # E.g. 'FileOne_2.0.0.txt'
    srcbase=${srcfile%_*}   # E.g. 'FileOne'

    # Set and check the path that the file will be moved to
    destpath=$destdir/$srcfile
    if [[ -e $destpath ]]; then
        printf "Warning: '%s' already exists.  Skipping '%s'.\\n" \
                "$destpath" "$srcpath" >&2
        continue
    fi

    # Make a list of the old versions of the file
    # shellcheck disable=SC2206 # (Bad warning re. unquoted ${kVERGLOB})
    old_destpaths=( "$destdir/$srcbase"_${kVERGLOB}.txt )
    # TODO: Add checks that the number of old files (${#old_destpaths[*]})
    #       is what is expected (exactly one?)

    # Move the file
    if mv -i -- "$srcpath" "$destpath"; then
        printf "Moved '%s' to '%s'\\n" "$srcpath" "$destpath" >&2
    else
        printf "Warning: Failed to move '%s' to '%s'.  Skipping '%s'.\\n" \
                "$srcpath" "$destpath" "$srcpath" >&2
        continue
    fi

    # Remove the old version(s) of the file (if any)
    for oldpath in "${old_destpaths[@]}"; do
        if rm -- "$oldpath"; then
            printf "Removed  '%s'\\n" "$oldpath" >&2
        else
            printf "Warning: Failed to remove '%s'.\\n" "$oldpath" >&2
        fi
    done
done
```

- The code is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean.  Two Shellcheck suppression comments are used because the unquoted expansions are necessary here.
- `srcdir` and `destdir` are set to constant values.  You might want to take them from command line parameters, or set them to different constant values.
- The code could be made shorter by removing checks.  However, moves and removes are destructive operations that can do a lot of damage if they are done incorrectly.  I'd add even more checks if it was my own data.
- See [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for an explanation of the "extended globbing" used in the code.
- See [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for an explanation of `${srcpath##*/}` and `${srcfile%_*}`.
- `mv -i` is used as a double protection against overwriting an existing file.
- All external commands are invoked with `--` to explicitly end options, in case they are ever used with paths that begin with `-`.
- Make sure that you understand the code and test it *VERY* carefully before using it for real.

Answer (score 0):

```
source_dir=./files/0
dest_dir=./files/1/
for file in $source_dir/*
do
  echo $file
  echo "processing"
  if [[ "1" == "1" ]]; then
    mv $file $dest_dir
  fi
done
```

Where processing and the 1 == 1 is whatever your 'prechecks' are (which you haven't told us)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is "files" "0" and "1" you mean in the code - line number 1&2.  "Precheck is I have to verify if these are the intended files that we have to put" its a manual activity which can not be automated.

Comment: It's just a directory name nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If your `coreutils` `sort` is newer than or equal to v7.0 (2008-10-5) after which `sort` command
supports `-V` option (version-sort), would you please try:

```
declare -A base2ver base2file

# compare versions
# returns 0 if $1 equals to $2
#         1 if $1 is newer than $2
#        -1 if $1 is older than $2
vercomp() {
    if [[ $1 = $2 ]]; then
        echo 0
    else
        newer=$(echo -e "$1\n$2" | sort -Vr | head -n 1)
        if [[ $newer = $1 ]]; then
            echo 1
        else
            echo -1
        fi
    fi
}

for f in Directory-1/*.txt; do
    basename=${f##*/}
    version=${basename##*_}
    version=${version%.txt}       # version number such as "2.0.0"
    basename=${basename%_*}       # basename such as "FileOne"
    base2ver[$basename]=$version  # associates basename with version number
    base2file[$basename]=$f       # associates basename with full filename
done

for f in Directory-2/*.txt; do
    basename=${f##*/}
    version=${basename##*_}
    version=${version%.txt}
    basename=${basename%_*}

    if [[ -n ${base2ver[$basename]} ]] && (( $(vercomp "${base2ver[$basename]}" "$version") > 0 )); then
#       echo "${base2file[$basename]} is newer than $f"
        rm -- "$f"
        cp -p -- "${base2file[$basename]}" Directory-2
    fi
done
```